# Add OnClickListner to CardView and get data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I wan to attach an OnClickListener to a CardView, so i can get the ID from the card

I have a RecyclerView that has a custom adapter for displaying the cards. This is how it's implemented.

I tried other examples in stackoverflow but it didn't work .

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Patient> patients;
Context mContext;
String idPatient;

public CardAdapter(ArrayList<Patient> patients) {
    this.patients = patients;
    }

        @Override
public CardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_card_view, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(CardAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.first_name.setText(patients.get(i).getFirstName());
    viewHolder.last_name.setText(patients.get(i).getLastName());
    viewHolder.id_patient.setText(String.valueOf(patients.get(i).getId()));

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //trying to get ID From card
            ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
            TextView idpatientview =(TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.idViewPatient);
            idPatient = idpatientview.getText().toString();
            PreferencesHelper.save(mContext, "idPatient", idPatient);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, BluetoothActivity.class);
             mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    }

      @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return patients.size();
    }

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            private TextView first_name,last_name,id_patient;
   public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        first_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        last_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewLastName);
        id_patient = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.idViewPatient);

   }
        }
               }
```

Comment: By getting the id, you mean getting the position ?

Comment: @DavidSeroussi No , i mean getting the id of the patient from the card or even his name because i need to use it in an other activity , I'm getting the data from Restfull service by the way.

Comment: Yes, but as I can see you are using an ArrayList to populate the card, which means if you get the position of the card, then you can use it as an index to retrieve the data from that card

Comment: @DavidSeroussi when i  do setText like     viewHolder.id_patient.setText(String.valueOf(patients.get(i).getId()));
i can see a result in my cardview but when i try to do a get it using even the id of cardview it doesn't work

Comment: I am sorry I didn't see that your onclick method was inside the onBindViewHolder. In this case it's much simpler. I am writing an answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your onClick method is inside your onBindViewHolder, then you can get the current data directly

```
String first_name = patients.get(i).getFirstName();
String last_name = patients.get(i).getLastName();
String id_patient = String.valueOf(patients.get(i).getId());
```

in your onClickListener, the id of the patient corresponding to the clicked card is simply `id_patient`, the first name is `first_name` and the last name is `last_name`. You can now pass the data to your activity (with an interface for exemple)

Comment: String id_patient = viewHolder.id_patient.setText(String.valueOf(patients.get(i).getId()));
the setText her return is  void I can't affect it to a string

Comment: Yes sometimes I do things a bit too fast, let me correct that